# how can i assign the double getting from setter method in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have setter method. I set the value from my first class and
I am able to get my value in second class. But when I call that double value to another method its showing zero.. Why is this happening ?
Here is my code.
In the setter I am able to get the value here :

```
-(void)setbasic:(double)basic1{
    basic = basic1;
    NSLog(@"setbasic: %f",basic);
    //console output
    //setbasic: 104234.000000
}
```

Set the value :

```
-(void)baseValue{
    Advanced *advace=[[Advanced alloc]init];
    double myDouble=([textfield0.text doubleValue]);
    [advace setbasic:myDouble];
}
```

After that i call that basic double value in my method another method in same class like this :

```
-(void)calculate{
    //here is the problem i can't get basic value
    NSLog(@"calculatesetbasic: %f",basic);
    //console output
    //basic: 0.0000
}
```

Here I get `0` only.
I call both method like this :

```
-(IBAction)Pressed: (id) sender{
    Advanced *advace=[[Advanced alloc]init];               
    [advace baseValue];
    [advace calculate];
}
```

Comment: What methods lives inside which class?

Comment: @Mats Stijlaart -(void)calculate method i need to get that setter value here..

Comment: @MatsStijlaart  -(void)calculate method is same class. where i assign the setter value.

Comment: In you next questions be more clear. Write in your code which class it is about, combine methods in the same code segment if they exist in the same class. and put in the .h. This gives more explanation for the people that will answer your question.

Comment: Is `baseValue` a method in `Advanced`? If so, why are you creating another instance of `Advanced` inside the `baseValue` method?

Comment: Please use punctuations in your question as it's nearly impossible to guess what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How I see it:

Your flow is like this:

```
->Pressed gets called.
   Makes an advanced.
   Calls baseValue in advanced.
     ->baseValue gets called.
       baseValue creates a new advanced
       retrieves the double.
       sets the double in the new advance.
   Calls calculate in advanced.
```

I think your problem is in creating the new advanced. You create it twice. First in your controller. Then again in your advanced method (baseValue).

Instead of:

```
baseValue creates a new advanced
retrieves the double.
sets the double in the new advance.
```

do:

```
retrieves the double.
sets the double in the **same** advance. ([self setbasic:value])
```

Comment: i can able to retrieve the double value i can't able load that value into another method.

Comment: Yes, but does your application work without the creation of the second Advanced object? And please do something about your english, its really bad. 'I'm able to retrieve the double value and pass that value into another method'.

Comment: yes your right my english very poor.i have develop thank you for your reply.